# Trying to make a foreign key in a table, SQL throws an error

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

Within my table of `studentTakingModule` I am trying to set the column of `pageID` in there a foreign key, which leads back to the primary key in the table of `pages`. Please can someone guide me as to where I have gone wrong as SQL throws this error at me:

[image: SQL Error]

DB Design:
[image: DB]

Comment: You probably already have data that violates the constraint.

Comment: Hi @PaulSpiegel you were right, I did have some data inside of `studentTakingModule` but it's weird I wouldn't have thought that would of affected me creating a foreign key relationship. Thanks Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run

```
select studentTakingModule.PageID
from studentTakingModule
where not exists (
    select 1
    from pages
    where pages.PageID = studentTakingModule.PageID
);
```

Presumably (based on the error message you received) the result will be non-empty. The values in the result are `PageID` values which do not exist in the `pages` `table`. If such values exist, you cannot create that `foreign key`. You will need to make sure that all the not `null` `PageID` values in your `studentTakingModule` exist as `pages.PageID`. Otherwise the reference your record should point to would not exist. This is what the error message is telling you.